# How to poll a keyboard key in C?

Tags: c

I am looking for some sort of alternative to kbhit() for Mac, that will allow me to poll the state of a specific keyboard key. My only requirement is that it not be blocking, or require me to hit the enter key. I saw some similar posts on this site, but they all seemed to be blocking.

I really just want to be able to run a loop and check whether a specific key is pressed or unpressed during each loop, without slowing down or blocking the rest of my loop.

Comment: A combination of `ncurses` and `epoll` on `STDIN_FILENO` have worked well for me in the past (completely single-threaded, of course).

Comment: Can you show me some links that might explain what you mean? Thanks

Comment: Well, just `ncurses` provides the `getch` function, which is like your `kbhit`. But you need a way to know when input is ready, which is where `epoll` comes in -- otherwise your program would have to block on the keyboard read.

Answer (score 0):

From c-faq:

"A collection of code fragments for writing kbhit"

http://c-faq.com/osdep/kbhit.txt