# Continuous keyboard input in C

Tags: c++, c, console

I am creating a console application in C. This is a game in which characters are falling down and user has to press that specific key on the keyboard. I don't know how to detect which key is pressed by the user without pausing the falling characters. When I use scanf the Program waits for input and everything pauses.
Please help me soon!

Comment: this is actually interesting .. looking forward to some answers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13035523/1119701

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without ncurses

Comment: You can try to hook a window-procedure and listen to events. Unlike `scanf` this should not block.

Comment: You can push the function to get keyboard input to another thread

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a function called `kbhit()` or `_kbhit` it is in the `<conio.h>` library it returns `true` or `false` depending whether a key was hit. So you can go with something like this:

```
while (1){
    if ( _kbhit() )
        key_code = _getch();
        // do stuff depending on key_code
    else 
        continue;
```

Also use `getch()` or `_getch` which reads a character directly from the console and not from the buffer. You can read more about `conio.h` functions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) they might be very useful for what you want to do.

Note: `conio.h` is not a standard library and implementations may vary from compiler to compiler.

Comment: with the getch() my game still pause and waits for input. I just don't need to press enter key after entering a char. That is not the problem!

Comment: @zaingz that is the reason you have to use `if ( kbhit() )` so that it "waits" only if something was pressed. But because it was already pressed when it comes to `key_code = getch();` it reads the key that was pressed.

Comment: Thanks a lot...This really helped me.
One tip for those who use Visual studio should add underscore "_" in the start of every conio function. i.e : _kbhit() and _getch()

Comment: Just to give an update, in ANSI C  currently, kbhit() and getch() are deprecated, instead _kbhit() and _getch() are used! Useful answer though :)

Comment: @SanketPatel feel free to edit my answer with this information.

Answer (score 6):

You may probably look for [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

> ncurses (new curses) is a programming library that provides an API
>   which allows the programmer to write text-based user interfaces in a
>   terminal-independent manner. It is a toolkit for developing "GUI-like"
>   application software that runs under a terminal emulator.

Also check [C/C++: Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/c-c-capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pr)

```
#include <conio.h>

if (kbhit()!=0) {
    cout<<getch()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Not very sure but if it would have been for graphics implementation then it could be done using SDL

Comment: ncurses is not feasible. Isn't there any thing in windows.h library?

Comment: The equivalent for ncurses in Windows is PDCurses. http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be the  non-blocking keyboard input  you are looking for.

```
void simple_keyboard_input()  //win32 & conio.h
    {
        if (kbhit())
          {
                KB_code = getch();
                //cout<<"KB_code = "<<KB_code<<"\n";

                switch (KB_code)
                {

                    case KB_ESCAPE:

                        QuitGame=true;

                    break;
                 }//switch
             }//if kb
          }//void
```

And as for the characters  falling down.. here you go.

[image: The Matrix falling numbers]

Code for if you are on Windows:

```
/* The Matrix  falling numbers */

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;


#define KB_UP 72
#define KB_DOWN 80
#define KB_LEFT 75
#define KB_RIGHT 77
#define KB_ESCAPE 27
#define KB_F8 66


/* Variables*/

char screen_buffer[2000]={' '};
int y_coord[2000]={0};
int x=0, y=0,dy=0;
int XMAX=77;
int YMAX=23;
int KB_code=0;
bool QuitGame=false;
int platformX=35, platformY=23;

/* function prototypes*/

void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void clrscr(void);
void setcolor(WORD color); 
void simple_keyboard_input();  
void draw_falling_numbers();
void draw_platform();

/*  main  */

int main(void)
{
  /* generate random seed */
  srand ( time(NULL) );

  /* generate random number*/
  for(int i=0;i<XMAX;i++) y_coord[i]=   rand() % YMAX;

  while(!QuitGame)
  {
      /* simple keyboard input */
      simple_keyboard_input();

      /* draw falling numbers */
      draw_falling_numbers();

  }

  /* restore text color */
  setcolor(7);
  clrscr( );
  cout<<" \n";

  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();

   return 0;
}

/* functions  */

void draw_falling_numbers()
{

    for(x=0;x<=XMAX;x++)
    {
        /* generate random number */
        int MatixNumber=rand() % 2 ;

        /* update falling number */
        y_coord[x]=y_coord[x]+1;

        if (y_coord[x]>YMAX) y_coord[x]=0;

        /* draw dark color */
        setcolor(2);
        gotoxy(x ,y_coord[x]-1); cout<<"  "<<MatixNumber<<"   ";

        /* draw light color */
        setcolor(10);
        gotoxy(x ,y_coord[x]); cout<<"  "<<MatixNumber<<"   ";
    }
    /* wait some milliseconds */
    Sleep(50);
    //clrscr( );
}


void draw_platform()
{
  setcolor(7);
 gotoxy(platformX ,platformY);cout<<"       ";

 gotoxy(platformX ,platformY);cout<<"ÜÜÜÜÜÜ";
 setcolor(7);
 Sleep(5);
}




void simple_keyboard_input()
{
    if (kbhit())
      {
            KB_code = getch();
            //cout<<"KB_code = "<<KB_code<<"\n";

            switch (KB_code)
            {

                case KB_ESCAPE:

                    QuitGame=true;

                break;

                case KB_LEFT:
                           //Do something
                    platformX=platformX-4;if(platformX<3) platformX=3;
                break;

                case KB_RIGHT:
                           //Do something     
                    platformX=platformX+4;if(platformX>74) platformX=74;
                break;

                case KB_UP:
                           //Do something                     
                break;

                case KB_DOWN:
                           //Do something                     
                break;

            }        

      }

}


void setcolor(WORD color)
{
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),color);
    return;
}


void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
  static HANDLE hStdout = NULL;
  COORD coord;

  coord.X = x;
  coord.Y = y;

  if(!hStdout)
  {
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  }

  SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdout,coord);
}


void clrscr(void)
{
  static HANDLE hStdout = NULL;      
  static CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
  const COORD startCoords = {0,0};   
  DWORD dummy;

  if(!hStdout)               
  {
    hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hStdout,&csbi);
  }

  FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hStdout,
                             ' ',
                             csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y,
                             startCoords,
                             &dummy);    
  gotoxy(0,0);
}
```